# What kinds of external resources a html page can reference and how

Tags: html

I am about to scrape few html pages with all linked resources. I want to be aware of all possible ways a html page can reference them. Currently I am aware of:

- External CSS: `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"`
- External JS: `script src="myScript.js"></script`
- IMG Tag: `img src="smiley.gif"`

Anything else?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#embedded-content-0

Comment: The existing answer is missing `<object>` (obsolete), `<picture>` (new), and `<input type="image">`… probably among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also:

- Inline Javascript
- `<iframe>`
- `<embed>`
- `<video>`
- `<audio>`
- `<source>`
- `<a>` depending on your definition of external resource

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ for a list of tags

Answer (score 1):

Do Hyperlinks count? e.g. href="http://www.example.com"